# Как выполнить две CMD команды в QProcess

Tags: qt, qt5, cmd, qprocess

Пытаюсь выполнить 2 команды CMD:

```
auto programmName = QFileInfo(QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath()).fileName();
QProcess consola;
QString command = "cmd";
QStringList commandArgs;
QString subcommand1, subcommand2;
subcommand1 += "TASKKILL /IM ";
subcommand1 += programmName;
subcommand2 += "DEL /Q ";
subcommand2 += QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath();
commandArgs << "/c" << subcommand1 << "&&" << subcommand2;
qDebug() << commandArgs;
consola.startDetached(command, commandArgs);
consola.waitForFinished();
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Ошибка: Неправильный параметр или аргумент - '/Q'. Введите "TASKKILL
> /?" для получения справки по использованию.

Как это поправить?

Comment: Выполняете одна за другой.

Comment: @AzizUmarov там две команды - первая: завершить процесс основной программы, вторая: удалить исполняемый файл программы. По идее потом я хотел бы добавить 3ю команду: переименование файла. Благодаря этому я смогу сделать систему самообновления программы.

Comment: @AzizUmarov поэтому команды должны быть отправлены и упакованы в одну большую команду.